# GORM domain class properties default values

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Maybe a silly question but where/how should I define default values for GORM domain class properties? For example when I'm creating a new Company object instance I want default value for property country to be "USA". I guess I could do it in create controller but it looks kinda dirty. Something like:

`def create = {
        def companyInstance = new Company()
        companyInstance.properties = params 
        companyInstance.accepted = "USA"
        ...`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Put it in the domain class itself

```
class Company {
    String country = "USA"
}
```

Comment: Will this always work? What if the property is of some user defined class type?

Comment: @rahulserver create an instance by calling the constructor

Comment: to be able to avoid that only we need default value :)